# Как сделать ::before на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

есть такой стиль

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    background: url(/img/uncheked.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Нужно его как-то реализовать на jquery, он срабатывает при клике на лабел тогда чекбоксу подставляется картинка.

Вот html

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree">
 <label for="User_agree">Згоден з правилами сайту</label>
```

нужно именно с помощью jquery, такая вот задача

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не самая лучшая идея использовать данный подход, это конечно реализуемо, но придётся много оперировать с DOM-деревом. (Будет необходимо создать новый DOM-элемент  и в него, динамически, подгружать нужные нам css-свойства). От теории к практике, для подобных нужд, в место псевдоклассов на подобии (:before или :after). Рабочий пример

```js
$('.checkbox-hidden').on('change', function() {
  var styled = $(this).siblings('.checkbox-styled');
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    styled.addClass('_checked');
  } else {
    styled.removeClass('_checked');
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  font: 13px/16px Segoe UI, sans-serif;
}
.form .checkbox-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.form .checkbox-styled {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  text-align: center;
}
.form .checkbox-styled:before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .23s ease-in-out;
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)
}
.form ._checked:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" action="javascript:null;">
  <input name="accept" id="form-accept" class="checkbox-hidden" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="form-accept" class="checkbox-styled"></label>
  <label for="form-accept" class="checkbox-label">Згоден з правилами сайту</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но как мне кажется принцип такой:

```
$('label').on('click', function() {$('input:checkbox').css( /* а тут применяйте свой css*/)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [jquery before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)?

Хотя, в принципе, раз Вы собираетесь это реализовывать на jquery, то Вам не следует один в один повторять логику css, а просто прикрутить к `click` метки обработчик и добавить картинку на полую ввода.

Понимаете? Вы переходите на jquery, вам теперь не нужны приемы css.

Comment: нет я знаю про эту функцию и она выполняет совсем другое не связанное со стилями